# Guzzle form_params not sending array to the server

Tags: laravel-5, guzzle

Im having a trouble of when sending an array value to the server, seems the server cannot accept array values or the guzzle failed to send the array format

[image]

did i miss something? or Im in a wrong page? first_name and last_name fields are able to reach to the end server, just this variables field not able to reach there.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I finally got it. If you have array to be passed on the API server, instead of using form_params you need to use the json as a form_params in order to send an array to the end server.

Comment: sorry sir  I will not do that again in the future